# What is the PHP equivalent of this perl regular expression

Tags: php, regex, perl, translation

How can I write this perl code using PHP?

```
$var =~ tr/[A-Za-z,.]/[\000-\077]/;
```

edit 007 should have been 077

Comment: PHP doesn't have fancy translations like Perl does.  You're probably going to want to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Comment: why don't you post your attempt so that people can help you improve it?

Comment: What is the Perl equivalent of this Perl expression? Your search list has 56 characters and you replacement list has 66.

Comment: @mob, 54 and 64, actually. The extras in the replacement list are ignored, so it's basically `tr/[A-Za-z,.]/[\000-\065]/`.

Comment: Don't the `[` and `]` count? By my reckoning the replacement list is `[\000-\066`. But the point is that it's almost surely not what the OP intended.

Comment: @mob, oh yeah, those `[]` aren't suppose to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback`
Perl

```
my $var = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,.';
$var =~ tr/[A-Za-z,.]/[\000-\077]/;
print unpack("H*", $var), "\n";
```

[PERL Live Demo](http://codepad.org/qxKKj4YE)

PHP

```
$string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,.';
$replace = preg_replace_callback("/[A-Za-z,.]/", function ($m) {
    $n = 0;
    if (ctype_punct($m[0])) {
        $m[0] == "," and $n = - 8;
        $m[0] == "." and $n = - 7;
    } else {
        $n = ctype_upper($m[0]) ? 65 : 71;
    }
    return chr(ord($m[0]) - $n);
}, $string);
print(bin2hex($replace));
```

[PHP Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QTZQAa)

Both Output

```
000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161716191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f30313233313233343536373839303435
```

Answer (score 4):

php has the [strtr](http://www.php.net/strtr) function that uses array key=>value pairs where instances of key in a string are replaced with value. Other than that, like @Rocket said, you can use preg_replace_callback to get your replace value. the matched character is passed in to a function and is replaced with whatever the functions returns.

Answer (score 3):

Someone said PHP doesn't have an equivalent of `tr///` (though I now see that it does as `strtr`). If so,

```
$var =~ tr/A-Za-z,./\000-\077/;
```

can be written as a substitution as follows:

```
my %encode_map;
my $i = 0;
$encode_map{$_} = chr($i++) for 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', ',', '.';

$var =~ s/([A-Za-z,.])/$encode_map{$1}/g;
```

This should be easier to translate to PHP, but I unfortunately don't know PHP.

(I'm assuming the `[]` in the `tr///` aren't supposed to be there.)